# How to successfully embed blob PDF response in IE11/Edge

Tags: angularjs, pdf, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I am not able to embed a blob url as an PDF in IE 11/Edge. There is a CORS issue and IE gives an 'Access Denied'. From my research on SO, I have realized that this is due to IE's inherent security restrictions. My question is is there any other way of taking the blob URL data response from the REST service and displaying it embedded in the browser. I want to avoid using any third party libraries.
The service returns as below:

```
function getTest(id) {
        miEService.get(id)
                .then(function (response) {                        
                        var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
                        $scope.pdfData = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileUrl);                        
                });


get: function (id) {
        var config = {
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/pdf'
            }
            , responseType: 'blob'

        }
        return $http.get(miEnv.services.eApi + '?$filter=id eq' +
            ' ' + id, config);
```

Finally inside the html the display is as below -

```
<object id="pdf" data={{$ctrl.pdfData}} type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" alt="pdf" class="view-pdf_document">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rest service returns the binary data of the pdf, you could just embedd the url in your page as an Iframe rather than the binary content itself. It should render the pdf. If not, I've had success in the past just having the pdf be a link and when you click the link it opens the request to the rest service in a new tab. If the issue is that you don't want the rest service to show up in the url on the page, then you might have to proxy the request through your own server.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question with the code. I am trying to use URL.createObjectURL() to create a URL out of the response which I get back from the service and then display it. But IE does not allow that. I am trying to figure out another way of taking the blob and displaying it instead of creating the blob URL.

Comment: @sdd I don't mean convert if, I mean set the frame URL to the rest service URL